# LINQ query on timestamp between 22:30 and 1:00

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am trying to use LINQ to get a list of entities where the timestamp falls between either 22:30 - 24:00 or 00:00 - 1:00 on a saturday or sunday and I am looking to set both timeframes in the one LINQ query but I have been unable to do so and have had to break it up as follows:

```
weekdayNight = intervalInformations.Where(ii => ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(22, 30, 0)
                                                     && ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(23, 30, 0)
                                                     && ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday
                                                     && ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday
                                                     && !dates.Contains(ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.ToShortDateString()))
                                                     .OrderBy(ii => ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp)
                                                     .ToList();


weekdayNight2 = intervalInformations.Where(ii => ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0)
                                                     && ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)
                                                     && ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday
                                                     && ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday
                                                     && !dates.Contains(ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.ToShortDateString()))
                                                     .OrderBy(ii => ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp)
                                                     .ToList();

weekdayNight.Add(weekdayNight2);
```

How can I write this query without needing to join two different queries

Answer (score 2):

Adding an `OR` between the two conditions defining time intervals should do the trick:

```
weekdayNight = intervalInformations.Where(ii =>
    ((ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(22, 30, 0) && ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(23, 30, 0))
||  (ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0) && ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)))
    && ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday
    && ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday
    && !dates.Contains(ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.ToShortDateString())
)
.OrderBy(ii => ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp)
.ToList();
```

**Note:** Your query appears to exclude the last half-hour between 23:30 and midnight. If this is not intentional, you can simplify the query even further:

```
weekdayNight = intervalInformations.Where(ii =>
    (ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(22, 30, 0)
||  ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0))
    && ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday
    && ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday
    && !dates.Contains(ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp.ToShortDateString())
)
.OrderBy(ii => ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp)
.ToList();
```